# Link lambda function to alexa skill kit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Hi i've created a lambda function that can recall items from my dynamodb table using the primary key.

here is the code i have

```js
'use strict';

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dclient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var getItems = (event, context, callback)=>{
    
    dclient.get(event.params,(error,data)=>{
        if(error){
            callback(null,"error occurerd");
        }
        else{
            callback(null,data);
        }
    });
};

exports.getItems = getItems;
//exportshandelrhandlergetItems = getItems;
```

it works fine but now what i want to do is set it up to work with alexa so i can ask alexa to query my table

can anyone help me on how to do this? ive created a skill and had it all linked but not sure how to do my interaction model

thanks

here is my intent schema

```js
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "date"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.CancelIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.HelpIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.StopIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "Cinema"
    },
    {
      "intent": "MyIntent"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow below steps,

1. go to https://developer.amazon.com/
2. Log in with your account
3. Click on Alexa
4. Click on 'Add new Skills'
5. Fill 'Skill information' and 'Interaction Model' section
6. Under 'Configuration' Section mentions you Lambda ARN like below,

[image]

Please copy below code as such to your Lambda function and just say 'Open 'YOUR SKILL NAME'' the Alexa should respond 'Welcome to the world of Alexa'

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    try {

        var request = event.request;

        if (request.type === "LaunchRequest") {
            context.succeed(buildResponse({
                speechText: "Welcome to the world of Alexa",
                repromptText: "I repeat, Welcome to the world of Alexa",
                endSession: false
            }));
        }


        else if (request.type === "SessionEndedRequest") {
            options.endSession = true;
            context.succeed();
        }
        else {
            context.fail("Unknown Intent type")
        }



    } catch (e) {

    }


};

function buildResponse(options) {
    var response = {
        version: "1.0",
        response: {
            outputSpeech: {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.speechText}</prosody></speak>`
            },

            shouldEndSession: options.endSession
        }
    };

    if (options.repromptText) {
        response.response.reprompt = {
            outputSpeech: {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.repromptText}</prosody></speak>`
            }
        };
    }

    return response;
}
```

Please find one sample in my GitHub (not using Alexa SDK),

https://github.com/vnathv/alexa-myfortune/blob/master/MyFortune/Index.js

Comment: HI, thanks for your reply. I've already done this; where im stuck is how to code my function to be triggered by Alexa skill kit.

Comment: @zuba I have added a GitHub link which shows a sample code

Comment: thank you, i'll have a look at it and se how it goes

Comment: im struggling to get alexa to trigger my lambda function, do i need to include any code in the lambda function? i keep getting The response is invalid

Comment: @zuba Do you want to drop your Skype Id? Will share screen and work this weekend

Comment: Yes please that would be a great deal of help. I'm available any time during the weekend at a time that suits you, my skype is zuhaibahmed96.

Comment: Hi are you available any time today?

Comment: ahhh I am extremely sorry. I totally forgot about this :(. Let me add you today

Comment: it's okay, not to worry, hopefully you can make time during the day

Comment: @zuba yeah I will try to connect my best. I am in UK time zone though. mean while I have updated a code sample in answer. Please copy the code as such and try. I have copied this from one of my alexa app in production

Comment: thank you, i'm also in the UK. I will give that a try now and see what i can do. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @zuba if this is not working please share your intent schema and sample utterances

Comment: I will attempt this now and update you, is there anything I need to add to my lambda function? I already have my lambda function and alexa skill linked

Comment: you need to build response according to Alexa response. That's what buildReponse of my sample code doing. Just to say a welcome that code should work if your intent schema is correct

Comment: i have added my intent scheme to the thread. I believe where im going wrong is my lambda function.

Comment: hmm, will have a look when connected to Skype. I am sure something simple to do

Comment: ive managed to get alexa to return with Welcome to the world of Alexa when asking to open my skill; how would i now go about implementing my lambda code for my skill into this?

Comment: Thanks i will do. My previous code would output what I was looking for in my lambda function. Would you be able to help with implementing this into the new code to output the response through alexa?

Comment: Can you zip your code and attach it to a drive? Also are you connecting with DynamoDB?

Comment: yes i will go ahead and do that now, and yes my lambda skill retrieves data from my dynamodb table using the primary key, although i do intend to query other parts of my table

Comment: are you able to access the folder?

Comment: hi are you still able to help with my skill?

Comment: hello yeah, I can still help you. I am going to through a hectic office schedule. Do you mind if I work with you one to one in few days? Meanwhile, I will create a sample code which connects to DynamoDB

Comment: ahh I think I have posted the sample code to another question you have asked. You want the answer to be here?

Comment: thats fine i've already had a look. I understand, thats fine ill keep at it until you're free

Comment: yes sorry i've amended that now, I didn't realise I had to change my lambda code to work with Alexa. But as for connecting to Alexa, you have solved that problem.